# Copy a range of sheets from Sheet "Cover Sheet" to Sheets.Count into a new workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros

I am trying to create a "client friendly" version workbook that will include all tabs from "Cover_Sheet" to the final sheet. The workbook has a macro to copy the "value" sheet multiple times, each time renaming it consecutively e.g value2, value3 etc. hence

I don't know how many sheets will need to be copied and wanting to use the `Sheets.Count` function. The workbook only gives me the cover sheet and the final value tab.

I have been trying to use the below:

```vb
Sub Activate_Sheet()
    Sheets("Cover_Sheet").Activate
End Sub

Sub ExportExcelWorkbookFinal()
' ----------------------------
' Macro to export the workbook and break the links
' which allows it to be sent on to clients.

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets(Array("Cover_Sheet", Sheets.Count)).Copy
    ActiveSheet.Protect "password"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.GetSaveAsFilename
   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You only get the "cover sheet" and the "final value" tab because you are telling it to copy `Cover_Sheets` and `Sheets.Count`.
`Sheets.Count` will return the number of sheets in the Workbook.
So if you have 5 sheets, your code is saying; Copy `Cover_Sheets` and `5`, `5` being interpreted as the 5th sheet, ergo your last sheet.

I'm not entirely sure exactly what you mean, but I assume you have a different macro that creates the other value tabs. If you want to copy all sheets, starting with the `Cover_Sheets`, and going to the end, you could make that array first, and then use what you have.
I use the index of the `Cover_Sheet` as a starting point, and go all the way to `Sheets.Count`.

```vb
Sub ExportExcelWorkbookFinal()
'
' Macro to export the workbook and break the links which allows it to be sent on to clients.

Dim sheetArr As Variant
sheetArr = Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(Row(" & Application.Sheets("Cover_Sheet").Index & ":" & Sheets.Count & "))")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets(sheetArr).Copy
    ActiveSheet.Protect "password"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.GetSaveAsFilename
   
End Sub
```

This will however still only set a password on the First sheet in the new workbook, Cover_Sheet. Not sure if that's a problem, since you didn't bring it up. But if it is, just replace `ActiveSheet.Protect "password"` with the following:

```vb
For Each wsheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    wsheet.Protect Password:="password"
Next wsheet
```

You could also fill the array in the more "normal" way, with a loop, but I find that one-line approach interesting.

```vb
Dim i As Long, sheetArr() As Variant
ReDim sheetArr(Application.Sheets("Cover_Sheet").Index To Sheets.Count)
For i = LBound(sheetArr) To UBound(sheetArr)
    sheetArr(i) = i
Next
```